# How to create Custom ListView items?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, blend

I'm trying to create a ListView whose items each have a rounded off rectangle and label. When the item becomes selected, I want the rectangle to go Blue, and the label Text colour to become white. Similarly, when the item becomes unselected, the rectangle will return to Transparent, and the label to black. However, I'll be adding Items dynamically using C#, so I think the best way to do this will be in XAML. Can anyone help? I've been looking in to using Styles and Triggers, as this seems a good way.

Comment: Styles and Triggers are certainly the way to go. There are lots of examples here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788747(v=vs.110).aspx. I'd give things a shot and try ask a more specific question if you have any issues.

Comment: Should ask technical questions instead of dull work.

Comment: @Joe Thanks! Surprisingly I managed to solve it...